# more than one delegate listen to an instance of uisearchbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Is there a way for more than one object to listen to void delegate methods of an instance of UISearchbBar?

For example, how does UISearchDisplayController know the search bar has its text string changed in:

```
– searchDisplayController:shouldReloadTableForSearchString:
```

While at the same time the table view controller that instances the search display controller can be the delegate of the search bar and know if text has changed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
@interface MultiplexingSearchBarDelegate : NSObject<UISearchBarDelegate> {
    NSMutableArray* delegates;
}

- (void) addDelegate: (id) theDelegate;
- (void) removeDelegate: (id) theDelegate;
@end

@implementation MultiplexingSearchBarDelegate

- (id) init {
    if ((self = [super init])) {
        delegates = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity: 16];
    }
}

- (void) dealloc {
    [delegates release];
    [super dealloc]
}

- (void) addDelegate: (id) theDelegate {
    @synchronized(delegates) {
        if (theDelegate && ! [delegates containsObject: theDelegate]) {
            [delegates addObject: theDelegate];
        }
    }
}

- (void) removeDelegate: (id) theDelegate {
    @synchronized(delegates) {
        if (theDelegate && [delegates containsObject: theDelegate]) {
            [delegates removeObject: theDelegate];
        }
    }
}

//add your UISearchBarDelegate methods here, following a pattern like this
- (void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    @synchronized(delegates) {
        for (id<UISearchBarDelegate> theDelegate in delegates) {
            [theDelegate searchBar:searchBar textDidChange:searchText];
        }
    }
}

@end
```

Then just set a `MultiplexingSearchBarDelegate` as the delegate of the `UISearchBar`, and add your delegates to the `MultiplexingSearchBarDelegate` instead of directly to the `UISearchBar`.

Answer (score 0):

Only one object can be the delegate and receive the delegate method calls. However the delegate can notify an many objects as you like, perhaps via delegate protocols you have written. You probably need to refactor a bit.